# Ajax continuous pull from database

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have literally just started programing with Ajax and cant get this to work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var oldAction = '';

function updateCheck() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'check_status.php',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.length != oldAction) {
        if (data.length == '4') {
          playSong();
        } else {
          pauseSong();
        }
      }

      oldAction = data.length;
    }
  });
}

setInterval('updateCheck();', 1000);
```

Does anyone know why this would not be working?

Thanks

Comment: use `if (data.length.toString() == '4')` || `if (data.length == 4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  `length()` is looking for an integer, but you are comparing it to a string.

If `oldAction` really needs to be a string, then you need to do something like this:

```
if (data.length != Number(oldAction)) {
  if (data.length == 4) {
    playSong();
  } else {
    pauseSong();
  }
};
```

Comment: Great!  Please accept the answer if it worked for you and let me know if I can be of further help!

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt I don't know why people ask a question here , find and even vote up the answer but forget to accept that!

Comment: I was waiting for the 5 minute limit so that I could accept it. I didn't forget.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function updateCheck() {
  var
    oldAction = 0,
    callAjax = function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'check_status.php',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.length != oldAction) {
            (data.length == 4) ? playSong() : pauseSong();
          }

          oldAction = data.length;
        }
      });
    };

  setInterval(callAjax, 1000);
}

updateCheck();

​
```